# How can I get this hamburger menu to turn into an x onclick?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've tried countless different css and jquery suggestions, and none of them have been working out.  Taking my current html and css into consideration, how can I turn my hamburger menu into an x?

I have tried doing it with css, using rotate 45 and -45, I have tried jquery, but I am just not doing it right.  It doesn't stay active, and it is usually out of position.

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class="acetrnt-toggle" data-click-state="1">

                <span class="line-1"></span>
                <span class="line-2"></span>
                <span class="line-3"></span>

    <div/>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {

    background: blue;

}

.acetrnt-toggle {

    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 60px;
}

.line-1, .line-2, .line-3 {

    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    content: '';

}

.acetrnt-toggle:hover span {

    cursor: pointer;
    background: #e7e7e7;

}

.line-1, .line-2 {

    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.line-1, .line-2, .line-3 {

    transition: all 300ms ease-in;

}
```

Here is the codepen --> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpaGzq

Comment: show us what you have tried so we can correct you, actually there is only HTML/CSS on your code

Comment: @TemaniAfif here is my updated codepen for what I most recently tried.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpaGzq

Comment: Can you show us what you have done with JQuery? Or have you not done anything and would be willing to accept JQuery? :P

Comment: @SamyokNepal Nothing of note has been done with jquery.  I am willing to accept.  Haha.

Comment: @AceLong I think JS/JQuery would be required, as CSS only manipulates how things look, not their state. Working on an answer now.

Comment: These might be helpful: [Tasty CSS-animated hamburgers by Jonathan Suh](https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers/)

Comment: @SamyokNepal I am starting to get somewhere as well!  I am using .addclass('active') in my jquery.

Comment: @AceLong I think `toggleClass` might be easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `:active`s to `.active`s and use `.toggleClass` to get the effect: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjYZaj

```js
$(".acetrnt-toggle").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active")
})
```

```css
body {
  
  background: blue;
}

.acetrnt-toggle {

 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 15px;
 width: 60px;
}

.line-1, .line-2, .line-3 {

 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 4px;
 height: 5px;
 width: 60px;
 background: #000;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 content: '';

}

.acetrnt-toggle:hover span {

 cursor: pointer;
 background: #e7e7e7;

}

.line-1, .line-2 {

 margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.line-1, .line-2, .line-3 {

 transition: all 300ms ease-in;

}

.acetrnt-toggle.active .line-2 {

 background-color: transparent;

}

.acetrnt-toggle.active .line-1 {

 background: #fefefe;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;

}

.acetrnt-toggle.active .line-3 {

 background: #fefefe;
  bottom: 10px
  position: absolute;
 
}

.acetrnt-toggle.active .line-1 {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 37px;
}

.acetrnt-toggle.active .line-3 {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  
  <div class="acetrnt-toggle" data-click-state="1">

     <span class="line-1"></span>
     <span class="line-2"></span>
     <span class="line-3"></span>

    <div/>
    
    </body>
```

Comment: // Thank-you!  I definitely noticed that it was supposed to be . instead of : and the toggleclass is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Best I could come up with, but it's very brittle:

html:

```
<div class="acetrnt-toggle" data-click-state="1">

                    <span class="line-1 left-slash"></span>
                    <span class="line-2 hide"></span>
                    <span class="line-3 right-slash"></span>

                <div/>
```

css:

```
.left-slash {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px, 21px);
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.right-slash {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px, -21px);
}
```

As for the JavaScript, you'd want to apply each one of those classes and remove them on click. I gather that you're trying to animate the hamburger into an X. The problem with the solution I proposed is that it is entirely dependent on the size of .acetrnt-toggle remaining static.

Answer (score 1):

even better

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
#nav {
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav span:nth-child(2),
#nav span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```